# Build errors while cross compile C source project with android standalone toolchain

Tags: android, android-ndk, cross-compiling

I m trying to build old c code with android standalone tool chain and it keeps failing on

following error :

```
fatal error: ftw.h: No such file or directory
```

Not sure how to include these headers from android.

Thanks,

Comment: The header file is not in the include path, you'll have to specify the path to it in your Android.mk file

Comment: Couldn't find this file anywhere in my NDK sysroot.

Comment: Should be in your jni folder in the android project.

Answer (score 1):

`ftw.h` is included in android-21 platform (ndk 10c):

```
MBA-Anton:android-ndk-r10c asmirnov$ find /softdev/android-ndk-r10c -name "ftw.h"
/softdev/android-ndk-r10c/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/include/ftw.h
/softdev/android-ndk-r10c/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64/usr/include/ftw.h
/softdev/android-ndk-r10c/platforms/android-21/arch-mips/usr/include/ftw.h
/softdev/android-ndk-r10c/platforms/android-21/arch-mips64/usr/include/ftw.h
/softdev/android-ndk-r10c/platforms/android-21/arch-x86/usr/include/ftw.h
/softdev/android-ndk-r10c/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64/usr/include/ftw.h
```

Answer (score 0):

This was an old message, but as I am on a similar ftw-hunt today:  as of my writing this, ftw.h does not exist in contemporary android ndk include dirs.

Here are external links to source code for ftw* which may be useful:

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/ksh/ksh-4/ksh/src/lib/libast/comp/ftw.c
http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/ksh/ksh-4/ksh/src/lib/libast/comp/ftw.h

Also, ftwalk.c is located as above but libast/misc/ftwalk.c (stackoverflow will not let me post a third link cause I'm a newb).